# Need help connecting to the internet but the option to connect to networks is not even listed

Tags: networking, drivers, dual-boot

I have an Acer Aspire running windows 7 and Ubuntu. I am new to Ubuntu so treat me like i know nothing.

I decided to install ubuntu so I installed it as a separate operating selectable on startup.

When I first got it running it showed up with a little box in the corner that said: "Network: Disconnected-You are now off line" I have tried a number of different things to get it to connect but so far nothing has worked. I can connect to my home network on windows 7 although i cannot connect to other or public networks.

I have an ethernet cable but that doesn't seem to help either. When i click on the network menu or whatever in the top right corner, I only have the options to VPN Connections,

Enable Networking and Edit Connections... I think that the problem has something to do with drivers but I am not sure. Other information: I am trying to connect to the Comcast Arris Router.

Comment: click on `enable networking` now you should be able to connect via ethernet. For wireless drivers check [here](http://askubuntu.com/q/47506/35775)

Comment: For whatever reason just plugging in the ethernet cable doesn't actually do anything. Any idea why?

Comment: Plug in the cable, open a terminal and enter `dmesg`. Do you see a message like `link up`? Please copy the last (up to 5 lines) into your question.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on the wifi chip set i would install windows wireless drivers http://jak-linux.org/projects/ndisgtk/ then mount your windows partition search for drivers wifi. The file your looking for is INF.wifi